# JSTree node with multiple selection/click options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I need the last node of a JSTree to present as list of individual buttons, horizontally after it. Each button has a different value that records a score for that last node's question.  I can't figure out how to fire individual items click events inside the list item. The click event only fires for the entire node.

![screenshot gui design] https://i.ibb.co/FKwDNFz/Capture.jpg

Any Ideas on how i could accomplish this? 
See attached image.

I have tried to add answer options as another subtree to question but that would display answers vertically and I need them to be horizontal to the right of the node.

I should be able to individual click the lettered buttons.

```
<ul class="question">
<li class="question jstree-open" data-jstree='{"icon":"fas fa-angle-right"}'>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8">
a. Points to hand that is hiding a toy (both when toy remains in that hand and when toy is transferred to the other hand, out of sight)
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
<input type="radio" id="asm-input" hidden="hidden" value="" />

<a href="#!" data-value="1" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary asm-option align-middle">&#x2B;/-A</a>
<a href="#!" data-value="2" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary asm-option align-middle">&#x2B;A </a>
<a href="#!" data-value="3" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary asm-option align-middle">&#x2B;/-</a>
<a href="#!" data-value="4" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary asm-option align-middle">&#x2B; </a>
<a href="#!" data-value="5" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary asm-option align-middle">- </a>


</div>
</div>

</li>
</ul>
.
.
.
```

Comment: where is the attached image ?

Comment: correction its in the link . ![screenshot gui design] https://i.ibb.co/FKwDNFz/Capture.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let links = [...document.body.querySelectorAll('a')];

links.map( link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', event => {
        let value = event.target.getAttribute('data-value');
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<ul class="question">
    <li class="question jstree-open" data-jstree='{"icon":"fas fa-angle-right"}'>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                a. Points to hand that is hiding a toy (both when toy remains in that hand and when toy is transferred to the other hand, out of sight)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                <input type="radio" id="asm-input" hidden="hidden" value="" />

                <a id="ppp" href="#!" data-value="1" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary asm-option align-middle">&#x2B;/-A</a>
                <a href="#!" data-value="2" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary asm-option align-middle">&#x2B;A </a>
                <a href="#!" data-value="3" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary asm-option align-middle">&#x2B;/-</a>
                <a href="#!" data-value="4" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary asm-option align-middle">&#x2B; </a>
                <a href="#!" data-value="5" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary asm-option align-middle">- </a>

            </div>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Dude!  That worked great! I'm obviously not super knowledgeable about DOM manipulation, thanks for the lesson!